# onBackPressed not going back to previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity, onbackpressed

I've created some activities for my project, but I have some problems when go from one activity to another

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transaksibaru);
        getSupportActionBar().show();
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.editJenis);
        KeteranganTrx = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editKeterangan);
        JumlahTrx = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editJumlah);
        JumlahTrx.addTextChangedListener(onTextChangedListener());

        SubmitTransaksi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);

        SubmitTransaksi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Checking whether EditText is Empty or Not
                CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();
                if(CheckEditText){
                    // If EditText is not empty and CheckEditText = True then this block will execute.
                    ProsesTransaksi(JenisTrxHolder,KeteranganTrxHolder, JumlahTrxHolder);
                }
                else {
                    // If EditText is empty then this block will execute .
                    Toast.makeText(TransaksiBaru.this,"Pastikan Semua Kolom Terisi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private TextWatcher onTextChangedListener() {
        return new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                JumlahTrx.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                try {
                    String originalString = s.toString();
                    Long longval;
                    if (originalString.contains(",")) {
                        originalString = originalString.replaceAll(",", "");
                    }
                    longval = Long.parseLong(originalString);
                    DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
                    formatter.applyPattern("#,###,###,###");
                    String formattedString = formatter.format(longval);
                    //setting text after format to EditText
                    JumlahTrx.setText(formattedString);
                    JumlahTrx.setSelection(JumlahTrx.getText().length());
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    nfe.printStackTrace();
                }
                JumlahTrx.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        };
    }

    public void ProsesTransaksi(final String S_Jenis, final String S_Keterangan, final String S_Jumlah){
        class ProsesTransaksiClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(TransaksiBaru.this,"Loading Data",null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {
                super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                if(httpResponseMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Transaksi berhasil di simpan")){
                    Toast.makeText(TransaksiBaru.this,httpResponseMsg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                    Intent IntentDashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserDashboard.class);
                    startActivity(IntentDashboard);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(TransaksiBaru.this,httpResponseMsg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                hashMap.put("JenisTrx",params[0]);
                hashMap.put("KeteranganTrx",params[1]);
                String a = params[2];
                a=a.replaceAll(",","");
                hashMap.put("JumlahTrx",a);
                finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpURL);
                return finalResult;
            }
        }

        ProsesTransaksiClass prosesTransaksiClass = new ProsesTransaksiClass();
        prosesTransaksiClass.execute(S_Jenis,S_Keterangan,S_Jumlah);
    }

    public void CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot(){
        int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        JenisTrx = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
        JenisTrxHolder = JenisTrx.getText().toString();
        KeteranganTrxHolder = KeteranganTrx.getText().toString();
        JumlahTrxHolder = JumlahTrx.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(JenisTrxHolder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(KeteranganTrxHolder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(JumlahTrxHolder))
        {
            CheckEditText = false;
        }
        else {
            CheckEditText = true ;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

When I press the back key on my device, it directly closes the app. What I want is when I press the key back in my device it will back to the previous activity. How to detect if there is previous activity then true back to previous activity.

Any help with this?

Comment: If you want to go back to an `Activity`, then don't `finish()` it.

Comment: if you didn't call finish on the previous activity then you will go to the prev activity

Comment: did you call finish() to back activity ?

Comment: i already try super.onBackPressed(); but the result is same, it will close the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {
 super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

 progressDialog.dismiss();
 if(httpResponseMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Transaksi berhasil di simpan")){

   Toast.makeText(TransaksiBaru.this,httpResponseMsg.toString(), 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   finish();// Remove this line from your asynctask.
   Intent IntentDashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserDashboard.class);
               startActivity(IntentDashboard);
            } else {
             Toast.makeText(TransaksiBaru.this,httpResponseMsg.toString(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: nice, but I got an error when trying to click back button in action bar in activity, can you help?

Comment: You should get on click listener of back button of action bar in your activity.

Comment: @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // todo: goto back activity from here

            Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

Comment: nice, fix it, just case android.R.id.home:
            finish(); thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the previous activities, you might have called `finish()` before/after `startActivity(intent)`, I suggest you to remove `finish()` method call there.

For eg:

To go from Activity A -> Activity B

You call

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Now in Activity B, you press BackButton, It will close the App, because there is no activity present in background stack to regain focus/ resume

To fix this, just remove `finish()` method in Activity A where you make intent call like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
// finish();    // Note: finish() is commented
```

Now, when in Activity B you press BackButton, it will resume Activity A

Note: make sure you are calling `finish()` in `onBackPressed()` in `Activity B`; which indicates that you no longer need this Activity(Activity B) and can resume last activity which was paused/stopped and is in background stack

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
  super.onBackPressed();
}
```

instead of this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    this.finish();
}
```

Comment: also shouldn't call finish on the prev activity

Comment: same, it will close the app too, any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `Intent` it might works e.g:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent gotoBack = new Intent(YourActualActivity.this, YourDestiny.class);
        //gotoBack.putExtra(USER_GLOBAL_SENDER, username_global); <-- Use this if you want to carry some data to the other activity.
        startActivity(gotoBack);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `finish()` or `finishAffinity()` to end that activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   finishAffinity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    this.finish();
}
```

It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think your'e before activity is u called intent time is finish as called so this activity finish then not go to previous.

> ```
> @Override
> public void onBackPressed()
> { 
>     startActivity(new Intent(TransaksiBaru.this,backActivity.class));
>     this.finish();
> }
> ```